# Flutter: issue with Image Zooming

Tags: dart, flutter

i am writing flutter app. i need to apply zooming functionality to images. 
i tried with plugins Zoomable_image and photo_view.
For Zoomable_image plugin image is scrolling out of the flutter view and when zoom out image is disappear.

For photo_view image is not scrolling and i unable to display full image with certain height and width.

can anyone please help me out in this issue or with any example.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have customized zoomable_image library to work with borders, If you want I can upload and send the link to you. Also, implemented min zoom which will help you better

Comment: Sure thank you. if library is available once i will work on that issue.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this - when I use photo_view or even a custom Matrix transformation - once you zoom in too far the image disappears or goes black.  Any help would be appreciated